# How to deal with big-appendable data in Google App Engine?

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

I'm using Google App Engine, and I have to deal with large files.

I need to append data to these files frequently.

If I use blobstore, I can't modify the file after I finalize it. To append something to the file, I must create a new file, copy the old file's content, and write the appended content. I think it's a waste to copy the old file because I just want to append append something.

If I use datastore, I can put the file into an entity's property as a integer list. To append something to the file, I can get the entity, get the corresponding property, append to the list, and put the entity back to the datastore. However, this method waste a lot of my datastore quota.

Is there any way I can use to just append something to my file, without touching the rest of the file's content?

Thanks!

Comment: are you using Java or Python? And JPA or JDO for the Datastore?

Comment: Can you explain your use case in more detail? Could you "append" data by storing it in a new blob, leaving existing blobs alone, and when accessing the data, merging all blobs into a single stream?

Comment: I'm using Java, without using JPA or JDO. I just use the methods DatastoreService and FileService provide to me to access datastore and blobstore.

Comment: I think appending new data in a new blob is a good idea. But to do this, I need to use a list to manage all the files that belongs to one file, and this list is also not "appendable".

Comment: My use case is that, I allow users to upload files. Once a file is uploaded, my app analyse the tokens in the file, and put the same tokens together. This token records the information of which file it belongs to, and where it's in the file. So, each token can be a list recording each place it appears at in each file. And I also need to retrieve some of the tokens when user request them. Thanks for your help!

Comment: @user1927728 You don't need a list - you just need to have a sort key for all your datastore entries. Sort them by write date and you have your 'file'.